# Is it at all possible to listen to an MBeanServer for registration of new beans?

Tags: java, jmx

.. where the MBeanServer in question is nothing special, the object returned from a `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` call, which apparently is a `com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer`.

I see no end of methods for listening to individual beans, but I need to listen to Create/Delete events on the tree as a whole.

I should clarify the context: a standard Oracle v7 or v8 JVM. There's no J2EE framework to consider, just the MBean server from [`ManagementFactory. getPlatformMBeanServer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getPlatformMBeanServer())

M.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be MBeanServer implementation specific but on JBoss you can use use the `MBeanServer.addNotificationListener(...)` and listen to start and stop events from the mbean. You can't listen to create/delete events from the server itself only events from the mbean.

Not sure if the Sun implementation sends these or similar events.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do is you register to listen to notifications from a specific MBean, and that MBean will emit notifications when a new MBean is registered. I forget which MBean it is, though, but I do know that it's possible.

EDIT: I found the answer, and it's detailed in this question: [Detecting newly registered MBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469657/detecting-newly-registered-mbeans)

Answer (score 0):

*I need to listen to Create/Delete events on the tree as a whole.*

You can't unless you own the impl. of the server. Hint: it's not always `com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer`, Application servers do install their own impl.